# Отчего и от чего

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как правильно будет: «Они прожигали друг друга злобными взглядами, от_чего хотелось закатить глаза». 
По всем правилам следует, что здесь должно быть раздельное написание, но меня почему-то коробит при одном взгляде на него. Я считаю, что нужно слитно, но вопрос только в том, насколько правильным будет это решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Они прожигали друг друга злобными взглядами, отчего хотелось закатить глаза.***

1) Здесь **отчего** — это **союз** (союзное  слово) в придаточном **присоединительном** предложении, пишется слитно.

*Гусь потянул за веревку, **отчего** раздался выстрел. Удобный момент для штурма был упущен, **отчего** войско понесло большие потери.*

2) Пояснение

Местоименное наречие ***отчего*** (=почему) пишется слитно, но его нужно отличать от местоимения с предлогом ПО ***от чего***, где сохраняется падежное управление и предметное значение местоимения (от чего это зависит).

В изъяснительных предложениях  наречия и местоимения играют роль союзных слов: Не знаю, отчего (почему) он такой хмурый. Не знаю, от чего (от какой причины) зависит его настроение.

В качестве присоединительного союза используется наречие ***отчего***: Не сдал экзамен, отчего целый день не в духе.

3) Источники

**Орфографический словарь**

**отчего, нареч. и союз** (отчего ты не ешь?), **но местоим. от чего** (от чего это зависит?; есть от чего в отчаянье прийти)

**Большой толковый словарь**

**ОТЧЕГО. I. местоим. нареч.** Почему? по какой причине? О. не пришёл? Не знаю, о. так случилось. **II. союз. Вследствие чего, по причине чего.** Старик улыбнулся, о. лицо его покрылось морщинами. Лошади переминались с ноги на ногу, о. изредка позвякивал колокольчик. <Отчего же? Разг. =Почему же? Отчего и, в зн. союза. =Поэтому. Болел, отчего и отстал.